# Solving a separable equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following separable equations subject to the given boundary conditions

a) $\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $x\sqrt{1−y^2}$, $y=0$ at $x=0$,

b)$(ω^2+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} = y$, $y=2$ at $x=0$ ($ω>0$ is a parameter).

**Edit:**
Sorry I wasn't clear, I am fine with everything up to and including integration, it's just the boundary conditions that I cannot seem to grasp.

Comment: So, wait --- you can't solve separable equations? Can you make a start? Do you know why they are called separable?

Comment: For part a, I have put the y's on one side and x's on the other and then integrated. I am confused about where the C comes in

Comment: When you integrate, you get some function of $y$ equals some (other) function of $x$, plus $C$.

Comment: Then you substitute in the boundary conditions, and out pops the value of $C$. Try it!

Comment: Ah, i see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For the first one, rearrange as
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = x\sqrt{1 - y^2} \implies \frac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} = x\,\mathrm dx$$
For the second one, we have:
$$\left(\omega^2 + x^2\right)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = y \implies \frac{\mathrm dy}y = \frac{\mathrm dx}{\omega^2 + x^2}$$

After integrating you'll have to substitute the initial conditions in order to find the constants.

**Example**
After integrating the first one, you'll get:
$$\arcsin y = \frac{x^2}2 + C\tag1$$
Now, substitute $x=0$, $y=0$ to get
$$0 = 0 + C \implies C = 0$$

Once you know the constant, substitute back into $(1)$ and solve for $y$:
$$\arcsin y = \frac{x^2}2 + 0 \implies y = \sin\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)$$

Comment: @mn_103: Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much :)

Comment: @mn_103: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(a)$ They are called separable because

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}}dy = xdx$$

integrate both sides. Then use the boundary conditions to find your coefficients.

Similar approach to $(b)$.

Spoiler:

> $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}}dy = \int xdx \implies \arcsin y = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$$

Now as $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ we have that

> $$ 0 = 0 + C \implies C = 0 $$

Finally

> $$\arcsin y = \frac{x^2}{2} + C = \frac{x^2}{2} \implies y = \sin \Big(\frac{x^2}{2}\Big)$$

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

a) $$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}=\int x dx$$

b) $$\int\frac{dy}{y} =\int \frac{dx}{\omega^{2}+x^{2}}$$

If you're studying separation of variables, I think you'd be able to evaluate these integrals.